# Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x) ^{n} =[ \lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)] ^{n} $

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x) ^{n} =[ \lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)] ^{n} $$
Hi,  I need help for proof this limit, which could be used arguments or results. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: Use the product rule for limits $n$ times. I suppose $n$ is a natural number.

Comment: @LarryB. I would assume both sides of the equality make sense, and as such that both limits exist. Continuity is a much stronger condition than we need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this result to make sense, we better have that
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)
$$
exists in the first place! But if we do, and assuming $n$ is a positive integer, then it follows from the product rule for limits:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to a} \left[ f(x)^n \right]
&= \lim_{x \to a} \left[ \underbrace{f(x) \cdot \ldots \cdot f(x)}_n\right] \\
&= \underbrace{\left(\lim_{x\to a} f(x)\right) \cdot \ldots \cdot \left(\lim_{x\to a} f(x)\right)}_n \\
&= \left[\lim_{x\to a} f(x)\right]^n.
\end{align*}